# Filtrar Elemento Option

Tags: jquery, html5

Como faço para poder pegar o objeto `option` com Jquery especificamente este:

```js
$('#nome_responsavel').blur(function () {
   var id = $('option[value="'+$('#nome_responsavel').val()+'data-toggle=p"]').attr('id');
   alert(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Nome</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_responsavel" list="list_nome" id="nome_responsavel" required>
<datalist id="list_nome">
<option id="1" value="teste" data-toggle="p">teste</option>
<option id="2" value="teste2" data-toggle="p">teste2</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#list_nome option')  // Captura os dois options dentro do #list_nome
```

Se quiser capturar o que possuir o `value` igual ao da caixa de texto está fazendo certo, porém use apenas um atributo por colchetes, caso queira dois atributos, use dois colchetes:

```
$('#list_nome option[value="'+$('#nome_responsavel').val()+'"][data-toggle="p"]')  // Captura os dois options dentro do #list_nome
```

Comment: Gostaria de colocar o data-toogle nesta seleção é possível? Pois tenho duas data list na página. E se ambas tiver com algum value igual pode dá problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta, olhe a edição. Veja se funciona

Comment: Funcionou top. todas opções de select fica entre []?

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta, Sempre que quiser selecionar um atributo, sim, fica.